# Save regression summary table automatically

Tags: r

I'm doing R programming.I have a time series data set with more than 10 independent variables and a
dependant variable. I want to run 10 individual regressions for each of those
independent variables.I 'm  using "for" command to get each column
of my data table and run a regression. I don't know how can I save summary regression
table automatically when I'm running this program. Would you please let me know
how can I save those tables automatically  as excel sheet or JPEG by writing
some codes.

Thanks
Afsaneh

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is always helpful. You could save the summary tables with something like: `res <- list() ... res[i] <- summary(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/971/art%253A10.1186%252F2193-1801-3-474.pdf?auth66=1413188823_2b9e60a749d6243f3ed0319007dd7b51&ext=.pdf) about producing ANOVA tables by hand or from an excel worksheet (I haven't tested it). If using ANOVA table produced by `anova` is sufficient for you, then this might work.

```
require(gridExtra)
mdl <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
grid.table(round(anova(mdl), 2))

# or save the result
jpeg("anovatable.jpg")
grid.table(round(anova(mdl), 2))
dev.off()
```